# How to correctly bridge Swift Errors with arguments to NSError

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, nserror

I've read the Swift Evolution [post on the improved bridging](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0112-nserror-bridging.md) and some other sources online, but still something is missing.

Given this custom `Error` enum:

```swift
    public enum MyNetworkError: Error {
        case networkOffline
        case httpError(status: Int)
        case unknown
        case systemError(errno: Int)
    }
```

An Objective-C app should be able to read the error object and somehow extract the error name (`networkOffline`, `httpError`, `unknown`, `systemError`) and the case arguments (`httpError.status` and `systemError.errno`).

The result of converting the above to `NSError` is surprising, and I'm trying to understand how to improve things:

```swift
    let nse_A = MyNetworkError.networkOffline as NSError
    let nse_B = MyNetworkError.httpError(status: 503) as NSError
    let nse_C = MyNetworkError.unknown as NSError
    let nse_D = MyNetworkError.systemError(42) as NSError
```

First, the generated error codes. It appears that the cases that have arguments, regardless of their order, get `code` starting from zero:

```swift
    print(nse_A.code)  // 2 (expected: 0)
    print(nse_B.code)  // 0 (expected: 1)
    print(nse_C.code)  // 3 (expected: 2)
    print(nse_D.code)  // 1 (expected: 3)
```

Given an error code reported by the app, now it's harder to tell the actual error case.

Second, I expected such a smart mechanism (especially since it's compiler-generated) to also copy the case arguments to the `userInfo` dictionary - but it doesn't.

Am I doing it wrong, or do I have to fully implement the `CustomNSError` protocol to get meaningful and consistent `NSError` objects? That's an option, of course, but I expected it to be done automatically (kind of like how `Codable` does its magic).

In addition, can the app get the error case name as a `String`?

For reference, the above snippets were executed in a Xcode 10.3 Playground.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Short answer:*  For integer-based enum error types the error values are mapped to `NSError` codes as expected. For all other error types (like enums with associated values) you have to implement the `CustomNSError` protocol in order to control the `NSError` code and user info.

*Some details:* Only for integer-based error types the code is bridged from Swift to `NSError`, for example:

```
public enum IntNetworkError: Int, Error {
    case networkOffline = 13
    case httpError
    case unknown
    case systemError
}

let err = IntNetworkError.httpError as NSError
print(err.code) // 14
```

That is a special case implemented in  [ErrorType.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift#L226). For all other error types, the default implementation is in [ErrorDefaultImpls.cpp](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/runtime/ErrorDefaultImpls.cpp#L25), and that returns the “tag” for enum types, and `1` for all other types. Example:

```
struct StringError: Error {}

let serr = StringError() as  NSError
print(serr.code) // 1
```

The enum “tag” is described in the [Type Layout](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ABI/TypeLayout.rst) document. For enums with associated values, this does not necessarily follow the order in which the cases are declared. That is why you observed “unexpected” `NSError` codes.

Therefore the correct approach *is* to implement the `CustomNSError` protocol, the compiler does not synthesize this for you.

```
extension MyNetworkError: CustomNSError {

    public static var errorDomain: String {
        return "MyNetworkError"
    }

    public var errorCode: Int {
        switch self {
        case .networkOffline: return 1
        case .httpError: return 2
        case .unknown: return 3
        case .systemError: return 4
        }
    }

    public var errorUserInfo: [String : Any] {
        switch self {
        case .httpError(let status):
            return [ "status": status]
        case .systemError(let errno):
            return [ "errno": errno]
        default:
            return [:]
        }
    }
}

let nse_B = MyNetworkError.httpError(status: 503) as NSError

print(nse_B.code) // 2
print(nse_B.userInfo) // ["status": 503]
```